# How to remove duplicate value in loop not using array

Tags: php, loops, for-loop

I want to remove or hide duplicate values in loop , It's not array.

[image]

You can see in picture `1/3`, & `2/2` is repeating so I want only once using loop. It's not return any array it's simple data so we can't use `array_unique`

```
$i=1;
$result = array();

foreach ($boxes as $key => $value) {




     foreach ($result as $k => $val) {
        echo $i."/".count($value).'</br>';
     }

    $i++;


}
```

**Expected Output**

```
REG-Pre-Cut Short    1/3

REG-Pre-Cut Long      -

PREM-Pre-Cut Short    -

PREM-Pre-Cut Short   2/2

PREM-Pre-Cut Long     -
```

Comment: please show the code which return this data

Comment: Is it long string ? show us your sample string to decide how to solve it

Comment: which code printing `1/3`?

Comment: When we print 1/3 in second loop then it's showing duplicate and we want it in second loop.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: @VinayPatil, I have updated my expected output.

Comment: @David thanks. Also, can you clean your code by removing unwanted/commented code.

Comment: Also need to specify `$boxes` value before starting the loop. `echo "string".$val['product_id'].'</br>';` what is `string` here?

Comment: I removed unwanted code , in box you can take any value  like  array('1/3','1/3','1/3','1/2','1/2','1/1') .. etc

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204831/discussion-between-vinay-patil-and-david).

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

1. First you create an array in the expected format.
2. Then use `array_unique` to remove duplicates.
3. Then you print out the array.

```
    $i=1;
    $result = array();
    $outputResult = array();

    foreach ($boxes as $key => $value) {
        foreach ($result as $k => $val) {
            $outputResult[] = $i."/".count($value).'</br>';
        }
        $i++;
    }

    $outputResult = array_unique($outputResult);
    foreach ($outputResult as $result) {
        echo $result;
    }
```